# Delete an object that was created in an arraylist in a loop Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I'm trying to delete an object that I created in an ArrayList:

```
turtles.add(new Turtle());
```

I want to get rid of the last turtle in the ArrayList, something like this:

```
turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1) = null;
```

Any ideas? Simply removing from the list doesn't work, and Java won't let me nullify in the above way. I'm pretty sure there is only be a single reference to a given Turtle object, as they are only ever created in this way.

P.S: The Turtle class is a thread, in case that matters.

Comment: There is no way to "destroy" an object.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is the reference to a running thread, and you're trying to get the thread to stop executing?

Comment: I no longer wanted the object to exist. Basically just wanted it to be garbage collected. I think I answered my own question though, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM garbage collector automatically frees memory associated with an object when there are no remaining references.

In this case, removing it from the list will work perfectly fine unless you've kept another reference to that object.

If you've passed this thread to an `ExecutorService` to be ran (or called the `start` method) then it wont be destroyed until after the `run` method finishes. If that's the case and you want to stop the thread immediately, there are various ways to break out of the `run` method.

Comment: Yes, I called the start method. It was set to run a very large number of times (200000 I think). Giving it a boolean flag to check each time it runs and setting the flag to false when I want to get rid of the object AND also removing it from the list worked.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
turtles.remove(turtles.size() -1 );
```

because:

```
turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1) = null;
```

will not work because you can only assign a value to a variable

The method `.remove(int)` removes the object form the `ArrayList` with the specified id.
here is a 'description' of the `.remove()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`ArrayList.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) like,

```
turtles.remove(turtles.size() - 1);
```

The method you use to create individual instances in `turtles` doesn't matter, when an instance is no longer reachable it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `=` operator, the `rvalue` is evaluated and is then assigned to the `lvalue`.
But in you code you were expecting the `lvalue` to be evaluated, which is not possible. That is why you are getting errors.
`ArrayList` privides its own method to remove an object from its list.

`turtles.remove(turtles.size() - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA, only creation of objects is in our hands, destroying them is at the discretion of Garbage Collector (GC).

When you execute the line **turtles.add(new Turtle())**, the JVM creates a new Turtle object in the java HEAP and adds the corresponding reference to list.

Similarly, when you execute **turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1) == null**, you are essentially getting the reference to that object and making the reference null. You are not actually deleting the object. Only GC takes care of deleting the object.

Note that GC is a lower priority thread, and we do not have any control to make it kick in. But we can request for GC to kick in using System.gc().

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for your help.

I've tried just using

```
turtles.remove(turtles.size() -1 );
```

and while it removed it from the list, I could tell that the thread was still running because it was still producing output. I'm pretty sure that the problem actually was that it was running (remember Turtle is a thread), and wouldn't die until it was done. I think I solved this problem by giving the thread an isAlive boolean that it checks each time run is called, and setting it to false and then removing it from the list when I want to delete it:

```
turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1).selfDestruct();
turtles.remove(turtles.size() - 1);
```

where selfDestruct does this:

```
isAlive = false;
```

I'm pretty sure this worked, I didn't see any leaks in perfmon.

Comment: This is exactly what I was describing in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't read your answer closely enough and missed the key parts, prior to researching more elsewhere. I've voted it up and accepted it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to destroy an object in Java you just have to set it `null`:

```
object = null;
```

Comment: Tried that. Java wants a named object in order to do this: `someTurtle = null;`, but because my object was created in a list, it doesnt have a name, and the only way to access it is using ArrayList's `.get()`, and this doesn't work: `turtleList.get(turtleList.size() - 1) = null`. Java doesn't like that and I just get the error message that the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: Have you read the question? the goal is to remove it form a list